# Convert view to Bitmap data to save as image | nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-angular

**Approach 1:**

Here is my **ts code**

```
 let makeImage = ViewModule.getViewById("makeImage"); 
  makeImage.android.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

[image]

Unable to get the view using "getViewById".

**View Code:**

```
<StackLayout id="makeImage">
                <Button text="Hi"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
```

**Approach 2:**

```
const view = application.android.foregroundActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    const bmp = android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    let x = imageSourceModule.fromNativeSource(bmp);
    imageData = x.toBase64String("png");
    console.log(imageData);



 Result: Able to get the screenshot of whole page of parent. Not a mentioned section.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the [nativescript-screenshot](https://github.com/enchev/nativescript-screenshot) plugin which of course internally uses same method for Android and comes with a equivalent for iOS too.

Always use the `loaded` event to access native view (`.andorid` / `.ios`) which ensures it's created.

**HTML**

```
   <StackLayout (loaded)="onLoaded($event)">
      <Button text="Hi"></Button>
   </StackLayout>
```

**TS**

```
  onLoaded(event) {
      const imageSource = plugin.getImage(args.object);
  }
```